# awk/sed - to print nth value after the match

Tags: awk, sed

My tf variables file has 200+ variables. Here are some conflicting variables when I try awk:

```
variable "vm_ami" {
  type        = string
  description = "ami image id used for setting up the vm"
  default     = "ami-5157cd3f"
}
variable "vm_mount_name" {
  type        = string
  description = "mount point for new device"
  default     = "xvdb"
  #default     = "xvdb"
}
variable "vm_device_name" {
  type        = string
  description = "device name for new drive"
  default     = "xvdb"
  #default     = "nvme1n1"
}
variable "elb_account_id" {
  type        = string
  description = "account id for elb"
  default     = "01234567890"
}
variable "account_id" {
  type        = string
  description = "Account number"
  default     = "0987654321"
}
```

I want to print `0987654321` (account ID). For that, I tried:

```
awk 'c&&!--c;/account_id/{c=3}' variables.tf
```

Gives:

```
  default     = "01234567890"
  default     = "0987654321"
```

.

```
awk 'c&&!--c;/account_id/{c=3}' variables.tf | cut -d '=' -f 2
```

Gives:

```
 "01234567890"
 "0987654321"
```

how can i print just : `0987654321` (without double quotes)

Comment: Also like you mentioned in my answer's comment section in case any value is like `ami-5157cd3f` then what should be the output then? Kindly do mention in your post and let us know.

Comment: `grep default variables.tf | head -n 3 | tail -n 1 | cut -d '"' -f 2`?

Comment: cos my other script needs the number in `account_id` as an input. so the script connects to a correct aws account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `sed`:

```
sed -n '
    /variable "account_id"/,/^[[:blank:]]*}[[:blank:]]*$/ {
        /^[[:blank:]]*default[[:blank:]]*=[[:blank:]]*"\(.*\)".*/ {
            s//\1/p; q;
        }
    }' file
```

**Explanation**:

Assumptions: In the input, there is exactly one line matching the string `variable "account_id"`, and there is exactly one line matching the string `default = "..."` between the first matching line and the line consisting of `}`.

The *address range* `/variable "account_id"/,/^[[:blank:]]*}[[:blank:]]*$/` matches the lines starting from the line containing the string `variable "account_id"`, and continues until the line consisting solely of a single `}`, optionally with leading and/or trailing blank characters (spaces or tabs). You can simplify the second address as `/^}$/` if you're sure that there will be no blanks in this line.

The regular expression `[[:blank:]]*` matches zero or more consecutive blank characters. The regex `^[[:blank:]]*default[[:blank:]]*=[[:blank:]]*"\(.*\)".*` matches the entire line which has the form `default="..."`, possibly with leading or intervening blank characters, and captures the string between double quotes (`"\(.*\)"`).

The substitution command `s//\1/p` replaces the entire line with the string captured previously (between double quotes), then prints it out. The empty regular expression `//` repeats the last regular expression match.

The `q` command exits the `sed` without processing any more commands or input.

Comment: @james Added an explanation.

Comment: For your range regex, you might consider `/variable "account_id"/,/}/` vs `/variable "account_id"/,$` Then the match is limited to the one `default` inside of the `{ ... }` Otherwise, this is an awesome `sed`! +1 from me...

Comment: @dawg Fair enough. Updated the answer

Comment: @M.NejatAydin Thank you! 

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
$ cat file
variable "vm_ami" {
  type        = string
  description = "ami image id used for setting up the vm"
  default     = "ami-5157cd3f"
}
variable "vm_mount_name" {
  type        = string
  description = "mount point for new device"
  default     = "xvdb"
  #default     = "xvdb"
}
variable "vm_device_name" {
  type        = string
  description = "device name for new drive"
  default     = "xvdb"
  #default     = "nvme1n1"
}
variable "elb_account_id" {
  type        = string
  description = "account id for elb"
  default     = "01234567890"
}
variable "account_id" {
  type        = string
  description = "Account number"
  default     = "0987654321"
}
```

You can use Perl to read the file as one string and use [multi-line regex](https://regex101.com/r/Gle639/1/) to parse the blocks:

```
perl -0777 -ne 'while (/^variable\h+"([^"]+)"([^}]+})/gm) {
                    if ($1 eq "account_id") {
                        $2=~m/\h+default\h+[^"]+"(\d+)/;
                        print $1;
                        }
                    }' file
0987654321
```

Or this GNU awk works as well:

```
gawk  'BEGIN{ RS = "\n\\s*variable\\s" ;  FS="\n"} 
            /"account_id"/ {
                for (i=1;i<=NF; i++) {
                    if ($i~/\sdefault\s/) {
                        match($i, /^[^"]*"([^"]*)/, matches)
                        print matches[1]
                    }   
                }   
            } ' file
```

Comment: Thank you! I get an output `0987654321%`. Just wondering how to get rid of %. I'll try to convert the regex that is compatible to awk.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk for FPAT to easily identify fields and then creating an array (`f[]` below) to map the field names to their values, you can just reference the values you want by their names:

```
$ awk -v FPAT='[[:alnum:]_]+|"[^"]*"' '
    { gsub(/^"|"$/,"",$2); f[$1]=$2 }
    /^}/ && (f["variable"] == "account_id") { print f["default"] }
' file
0987654321
```

With that approach it's trivial to test whatever you like and print whatever you like in whatever order you like, e.g.:

```
$ awk -v FPAT='[[:alnum:]_]+|"[^"]*"' -v OFS=',' '
    { gsub(/^"|"$/,"",$2); f[$1]=$2 }
    /^}/ && ( (f["variable"] == "account_id") || (f["description"] ~ /new/) ) {
        print f["description"], f["default"]
    }
' file
mount point for new device,xvdb
device name for new drive,nvme1n1
Account number,0987654321
```

Comment: @vgersh99 You're welcome. It's not unorthodox, though, it's a very common awk idiom - any time you have name-value pairs in your input you first create an array to hold that mapping and then simply access the values by their names whenever and however you like.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit heavy weight and more of a thought experiment, but that file is basically [tcl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tcl) syntax, which means it's easy to use tcl to create a simple [DSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language) to parse the file and then extract the desired information.

```
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh

# Create a new sandboxed interpreter and create functions to store
# variables and their sub-fields in an array.  Treat the sub-fields as
# commands of their own to be evaluated instead of just doing a
# straight list search for default to avoid things like
# # default = "bad" matching.
set i [interp create -safe]
interp eval $i {
    proc type {_ arg} {
        global vars varname
        set vars($varname,type) $arg
    }
    proc description {_ arg} {
        global vars varname
        set vars($varname,description) $arg
    }
    proc default {_ arg} {
        global vars varname
        set vars($varname,default) $arg
    }
    proc variable {name body} {
        global varname
        set varname $name
        eval $body
    }
}

lassign $argv filename varname
# Evaluate the file
interp invokehidden $i source $filename
# And extract the default argument of the given variable
puts [interp eval $i [list set vars($varname,default)]]
```

Sample usage:

```sh
$ ./getvar variables.tf account_id
0987654321
```